# Elastic beanstalk fails to create

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to run beanstalk with java installed on it very quickly.

So what I do is just open the beanstalk console and after creating the application I create the environment and in the environment pre configuration I chose  java.

Then after clicking the create button I get some errors:

```
Creating security group named: awseb-e-rnwzmmymhx-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-SXHGXGDOF5PN failed Reason: Resource creation cancelled

Stack named 'awseb-e-rnwzmmymhx-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBEIP, AWSEBSecurityGroup].
```

Or the more complete error stack is as follow:
[image]

I never attached any EIP and I just let beanstalk handle it . What is the problem?

Should I configure anything else? (Any idea is appreciated.)

Or better to ask this way: Do we need to attach EIP to beanstalk to have it work or there is a workatound using rout53?

Answer (score 13):

Each account has a maximum EIP limit (default is 5). Elastic BeanStalk is not able to get an EIP allocated since your account already used the maximum number of EIPs. You have at least two options:

- Release unused EIP (making sure it is not used)
- Raise a support request to increase the EIP limit. Usually it is fulfilled within hours

[AWS Elastic IP Address Limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-limit)

Comment: Thanks a lot. So does this mean that elastic beanstalk will assign EIP and we do not have a choice to use beanstalk without EIP?

Comment: Lets say we have 10 different projects in 10 different beanstalk so does this means that we need to have 10 EIP and there is no way to have them work without increasing the limit? if that is the case then maybe it is not a good choice to use beanstalk at all!!

Comment: In general, AWS limits are set pretty low to protect against costly accidents. As @helloV mentions, though, it's very easy to request that the limit be raised.

Answer (score 6):

Launching the environment with a load balancer allows you to avoid assigning an EIP.

See here: [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/698007/launch-instances-via-elastic-beanstalk-without-elastic-ip-configured/869329#869329)